# Determine if an adjacency matrix has a cycle and then output that cycle

Tags: c++, graph, cycle, adjacency-matrix

so I have 2 functions :

**UPDATED**

```
unordered_map<int, bool> visited2;
vector<vector<int>> elements2D;


bool DFSDetectCycle(int vertex){
    s.push(vertex);
    while(!s.empty()){
        int np_vertex = s.top();
        s.pop();
        if (visited2[np_vertex] == true){
            return true;
        }
        visited2[np_vertex] = true;
        for (int i = 0; i<elements2D.size(); i++){
            if(elements2D[np_vertex][i] != 0){
                if(DFSDetectCycle(i)){
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return false;   
}

bool hasCycle(vector<vector<int>> v){
    if (v.empty()){
        return false;   
    }
    for (int i = 0; i<v.size(); i++){
           if (!visited2[i]){
                      if(DFSDetectCycle(i)){
                          return true;
                      } 
           }
    }
    return false;
}
```

And in my main function I call it like this:

```
if (hasCycle(elements2D)){
        for (int i = 0; i<elements2D.size(); i++){
            if (!visited2[i]){
                DFSDetectCycle(i);
            }       
        }
}else{
        cout << "No cycles." << endl;
}
```

So basically, the input is going to look like this:

```
g++ -o GraphProcessor.o GraphProcessor.cpp -std=c++11
./GraphProcessor.o graph1.txt
```

And the output should look like this:

```
Connected components:
{0,1,2,4,7}
{3}
{5,6}
A cycle: 0 1 4 2
```

But my output looks like this:

```
Connected components:
{0,1,4,2,7}
{3}
{5,6}
No cycles.
```

graph1.txt looks like this:

```
0 2 6 0 0 0 0 3
2 0 0 0 4 0 0 1
6 0 0 0 3 0 0 2
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 4 3 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 7 0
0 0 0 0 0 7 0 0
3 1 2 0 0 0 0 0
```

Do not worry about the connected components part, that is not my problem right now. My problem is that my code is not properly detecting cycles in the graph and is not outputting them properly either. It seems as if my hasCycle() function is constantly giving a false statement, but I am not really sure why. elements2D is my matrix I am using, since it was read from a file, I needed somewhere to store it. For my visited2 function, I use an unordered_map in order to keep boolean values on whether or not I have visited the vertices or not. I know that if I have visited a vertex again, then I have a cycle. But I am not sure how to modify my algorithm in order to obtain a result like that.

Thanks again for any help.

Comment: Have you reset `visited2` array after finding connected components?

Comment: I'm sorry I should have clarified. For the connected components part, I use an unordered_map called visited. I initialized this new unordered_map called visited2 for cycles.

Answer (score 0):

1. You are calling `DFSDetectCycle` recursively without using it's return value. I suggest you check if recursive call return true, and return it is so.
2. You are specifically skipping the cycles because you filter the recursive calls with `if(elements2D[np_vertex][i] != 0 && !visited2[i])` - which means you will not go into already visit vertexes, skipping the cycles.

In addition, there are no prints in the code that would yield the required output...

Comment: I have done what you said and I believe it is working now. I have updated the code above. But I am not sure where to put the print statements in order to output the cycles. Do you think you could give me some indication as to where to go from here?

Comment: Try to add the print just before the ‘return true’ which you just added. It will give you the cycle print, but backwards

Answer (score 0):

You should remove `visited[i]` checking from `if(elements2D[np_vertex][i] != 0 && !visited2[i])`, because if you already visited `i`, then removing this checking can detect it. And if it finds cycle, you should return it immediately.

```
if(elements2D[np_vertex][i] != 0){
    if (DFSDetectCycle(i)) return true;
}
```

Another issue is if there exist edges `0->1` and `1->0`, then they make a cycle. You need more work to find largest cycle.

Comment: Unfortunately, I get the same output. It says no cycles.

Comment: Is there any way to upload a runnable program so that someone can help you?

Comment: I am sorry, I am not sure where to see the answer. Could you please provide a link? Thanks for the help by the way.

Comment: I have edited my answer under which we are commenting.

Comment: Okay, I have changed it. But now, I am unsure as to where to put the print statements in order to output the cycles. Where should I put them?

Comment: I have changed several things. If you have any question or found any bug, let me know. Plz check [this link](https://codeshare.io/5OBWpg)